# Which Collection type is most appropriate for a constantly updated, fixed-size array of Strings?

Tags: java, android, collections

I have come across a situation where I require a `Collection` type in Android that can hold `String` objects and meet the following criteria:

- It has a fixed size (say `10`) .
- Objects will only ever be added from one end of the `Collection`
- As a new object is added, all other objects automatically shuffle along one space to accommodate it.
- If the `Collection` is full (all `10` spaces occupied), then as one object is added from one end, the object from the other end is removed.
- It is possible to iterate over the contents of the `Collection` in either direction at any time, and retrieve the object at each position.

From my experience with collection types, I felt something like a `Queue` or `LinkedList` would be suitable, although I have never used either one personally. However, some of the terminology in the Android Docs has me confused over whether they would meet my requirements.

For instance, in the documentation for [Queue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue.html), it is stated:

> Queues typically, but do not necessarily, order elements in a FIFO (first-in-first-out) manner...

Which sounds ideal, but when I consider the `add()` and `offer()` methods, they both specify:

> Inserts the specified element into this queue if it is possible to do so immediately without violating capacity restrictions.

Which sounds like the opposite of what I am after.

For [LinkedList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html), the description includes the following line:

> This class is primarily useful if you need queue-like behavior.

Which is perfect, but again later on it alludes to the fact that `LinkedList` is useful when a flexible size is required.

> It may also be useful as a list if you expect your lists to contain zero or one element, but still require the ability to scale to slightly larger numbers of elements.

And on [this tutorial site](http://www.mycstutorials.com/articles/data_structures/linkedlists):

> The major benefit of linked lists is that you do not specify a fixed size for your list. The more elements you add to the chain, the bigger the chain gets.

Would someone please be able to clarify whether one of these types would be suitable for my situation?

Comment: For a size of ten it barely matters, but insertion at the beginning indicates a linked list.

Comment: @EJP An insertion at the beginning requires a deletion at the end.

Comment: @PPartisan How about using a Circular Queue?

Comment: for whatever the problem... `ArrayList` will hit the caches/registers better or mostly better than any other... I´d go with `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Collection` that fits nearly all your requirements - it's the [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)!

Unfortunately it falls short in one aspect, to quote:

> Array deques have no capacity restrictions; they grow as necessary to support usage.

On the upside:

> This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue.

Plus, if you base your design on an existing class, there is less space to make a mistake.

---

So, how do you change the `ArrayDeque` behavior to not resize when adding elements, but rather throw off old ones? Easy - all additions go through one of two methods: `addFirst(E e)` and `addLast(E e)`. The methods are public, hence can be overriden.

Thus, I present to you a version of `ArrayDeque` that does not resize:

```
private final int maxSize;
public MyArrayDeque(int maxSize) {
    super(maxSize);
    this.maxSize= maxSize;
}

@Override
public void addFirst(E e) {
    if (maxSize == size()) 
        removeLast();
    super.addFirst(e);
}

@Override
public void addLast(E e) {
    if (maxSize == size()) 
        removeFirst();
    super.addLast(e);
}
```

And that's it. Of course you should also modify the behavior of `clone()` and the serialization methods and what not if you want to be really thorough, but that's optional for most use cases. Also, don't show this code to any OOP purists, this isn't very nice usage of inheritance =)

---

If you're striving for performance, you may want to actually copy the code from the class and do the modifications in-place. That will allow you to remove several checks and methods that are redundant when resizing is impossible. It will also allow for quicker for-loops without creating an `Iterator` (by simply taking the code in the `Iterator`  - it's close in spirit to @T.J. Crowder's version, but uses bitwise operators, since the array is a power of 2 length).

Answer (score 3):

`LinkedList` would certainly work. The "add" logic is just:

```
list.add(newItem);
if (list.size() > MAX_SIZE) {
    list.remove(0);
}
```

If you need hyper-efficiency, a `String[MAX_SIZE]` might be appropriate, with a `current` index saying where you were in it (e.g., a ring buffer). "Add" logic for that is:

```
buffer[current] = newItem;
current = (current + 1) % MAX_SIZE;
```

That last line moves to the next spot, wrapping around to `0` again if necessary.

Assuming you pre-fill it (e.g., it's never empty or partially-empty), looping logic in order added is:

```
for (int index = (current + 1) % MAX_SIZE; index != current; index = (index + 1) % MAX_SIZE) {
    // ...
}
```

If it may be empty or partially-empty, and assuming `null` isn't a valid non-empty value, you'd do the same thing but skip `null`s.

Comment: @TJCrowler Wouldn't a circular queue implemented using an array make more sense?

Comment: @ChetanKinger: I'm not saying that you would write the addition/access code everywhere you need it. You might well (presumably would) want to wrap this up into a class with an API appropriate to your needs (which may be `Queue`, or not).

Comment: @TJCrowder So a queue (ideally circular) implemented using a linked list? That makes sense +1

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Very interesting, especially the clever `String[]` solution with the `%` operator. I'm going to try this out and will get back to you.

Comment: While the idea is certainly good, the code looks like a home-brew reimplementation of the `ArrayDeque`. Why not just use the code from there?

Comment: @Ordous: [*"Array deques...grow as necessary to support usage"*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hence "use the code from there" rather than "just use the `ArrayDeque`". You'll only need to change 2 lines in the class code (and delete several methods no longer required) to stop it from growing. And *that* code was already optimized and benchmarked extensively by specialists.

Comment: @Ordous: Gotcha. Yeah, that is a very good idea indeed. Good enough, in fact, to justify posting as an answer, or editing into the above (we can make it a CW if you like).

Comment: Sure, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Don't be lazy do it yourself!

```
public class Collection<T> implements Iterable<T>, RandomAccess{
    private final Object[] data;
    private int size = 0;

    public enum Direction{
        LEFT,
        RIGHT
    }

    private Direction direction = Direction.LEFT;

    public Collection(int capacity){
        data = new Object[capacity];
    }

    public void setDirection(Direction direction){
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public void add(T item){
        if(size < data.length){
            switch (direction){
                case LEFT:
                    data[data.length - size] = item; 
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    data[size] = item;
                    break;
            }
            size++;
        }
        else {
            switch (direction) {
                case LEFT:
                    System.arraycopy(data, 1, data, 0, data.length - 1);
                    data[0] = item;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    System.arraycopy(data, 1, data, 0, data.length - 1);
                    data[data.length - 1] = item;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void remove(){
        if(size == 0){
            return;
        }
        switch (direction){
            case LEFT:
                remove(data.length - size);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                remove(size);
                break;
        }
    }

    public int size(){
        return size;
    }

    private void remove(int index) {
        System.arraycopy(data, index + 1, data, index, data.length - 1 - index);
        data[data.length - 1] = null;
    }


    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            private int current = direction == Direction.RIGHT ? 0 : data.length - 1;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                switch (direction){
                    case LEFT:
                        return current > 0;
                    case RIGHT:
                    default:
                        return current < data.length;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                current += direction == Direction.RIGHT ? 1 : -1;
                Object result = data[current];
                //noinspection unchecked
                return (T) result;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                Collection.this.remove(current + (direction == Direction.RIGHT ? -1 : 1));
            }
        };
    }
}
```